# Laravel 5 How to Pass 2 Models to a Form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, model, laravel-5

I have form and i am using form model binding. My form is

```
{!! Form::model($vehicle,['url' => '/pages/store']) !!}                                   
    <table style="width:650px; margin-left: 4px;" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>Brand</td>
                <td>License Plate</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{!! Form::text('id' ,null , ['readonly'], ['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!! Form::text('model' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::select('brand_id', $brands, null, ['id'=>'brandBox', 'style' => 'width:150px;']) !!}
                </td>
                <td>{!! Form::text('licenseplate' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Client</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{!! Form::select('representive_client_id', $clients, null, ['id'=>'clientSelectBox', 'class' => 'selectbox']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Telephone Number</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('tel_number' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Adress</td>
                <td colspan="2">{!! Form::textarea('address' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control','style'=>'height:60px;']) !!}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="buttoncontainer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $first -> id ) }}"><<</a>&nbsp;
        @if($previous)
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $previous ) }}">PREVIOUS</a>&nbsp;
        @endif
        @if($next)
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $next ) }}">NEXT</a>&nbsp;
        @endif
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ URL::to( 'pages/vehicleprocess/' . $last -> id ) }}">>></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="add">EKLE</a>&nbsp;
        {!! Form::submit('EDIT', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}&nbsp;
        {!! Form::submit('NEW RECORD', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}&nbsp;
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am passing the `$vehicle` as

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::where('vehicles.id',$id)->join('clients', 'vehicles.representive_client_id', '=', 'clients.id')->first();
```

Store Function

```
$client = new Client;
$client -> full_name = $client_id;
$client -> tel_number = $tel_number;
$client -> mobile_number = $mobile_number;
$client -> save();

$last_client_id = $client -> id;

$input = Request::except('client_id');
$vehicle = Vehicle::create($input);

$u_vehicle = Vehicle::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
$u_vehicle -> update(array('client_id' => $last_client_id));
```

I am able to see all values of these fields in my view but when it comes to store a new record to my database i am getting this error

> Column not found Unknown column 'tel_number'

Guess i need to pass 2 models (Vehicle and Client) to the form but not sure how to make it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code for when you attempt to store the vehicle. If you are trying to update a relation to vehicle you do not need to pass two models to the view you can update via relationship: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: @haakym i need to update both vehicle and client by using this form

Comment: Sure thing, and I'm assuming they're related - right? Can you edit/update your question with the code that tries to store the models in the DB and I'll be happy to help. This is the code that is causing the error. Thanks.

Comment: @haakym i have updated the question please take a look at it

Comment: How are you determining if it's a new record or update, your update and new record button will submit to the exact same place unless you're using javascript?

Comment: @haakym u can assume that it is a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you need to pass your view a instance of `Vehicle` with `Client` - I know you're trying to do that with the join but I'm guessing that isn't the right way to do it. I set up a clean install with Laravel and it appears to work when you set up the relationship on the model.

I'm unsure what your relationships are so let's assume a `Client` has one `Vehicle` so the `Vehicle` belongs to the `Client`. So we can put your relationship in your `Vehicle.php`

```
public function client() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Client'); // or whatever the namespace to your class is
}
```

See more here on defining relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Then when you load the model in your view you can do this:

```
$vehicle = \App\Vehicle::with('client')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

The important part being: `with('client')`

Then any text fields with `Client` attributes should be populated with the existing data.

I hope that helps, if you need more help please let me know. I've got sample code of it working in a blank laravel project so I can throw that up on github if you need to see it.

Comment: That works thanks ! But how to get a text box value that is defined as `{!! Form::text('representive[tel_number]' ,null ,['class' =>'textboxlong form-control', 'style'=>'height:23px;']) !!}`

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working. Is Representative another entity in your DB that's linked to vehicle or client? If so just append `->with('representative')` to the query before loading the view after setting up a relation.

Comment: It is the name of relation function

Comment: In `Vehicle` right? What is the relation for, `Client` or something else?